# API calls made using axios are "canceled" but the exact same code works on all platforms

Tags: ios, vue.js, axios, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I launched my website and tested across all browsers on the desktop.  Everything looks good.

But when I test on my iPhone, iPad, and another iPhone the API calls don't finish.  I'm specifically seeing the call was "canceled".

This happens on all browsers on the across all Apple devices I tested.  But I can't replicate this issue anywhere else.  Any suggestions?

Running:
Nuxt, Vuetify, VeeValidate, PWA, SSR

I've tried using an emulator to get debugging output and API call info.  The POST calls fail immediately.

Seeing these errors before the POST fails 
69f0966….js:2 ReferenceError: Can't find variable: performancehide @ 69f0966….js:2h @ 69f0966….js:2
69f0966….js:2 ReferenceError: Can't find variable: performanceshow @ 69f0966….js:2m @ 69f0966….js:2
69f0966….js:2 ReferenceError: Can't find variable: performancehide @ 69f0966….js:2h @ 69f0966….js:2
69f0966….js:2 ReferenceError: Can't find variable: performanceshow @ 69f0966….js:2m @ 69f0966….js:2
69f0966….js:2 ReferenceError: Can't find variable: performancehide @ 69f0966….js:2h @ 69f0966….js:2
69f0966….js:2 ReferenceError: Can't find variable: performanceshow @ 69f0966….js:2m @ 69f0966….js:2
69f0966….js:2 ReferenceError: Can't find variable: performance

```
          postLogin() {
            this.$validator.validateAll().then(x => {
                if (x)
                {
                    this.validateLogin()
                }
            }).catch(e => {  })
        },
        validateLogin: function() {
            const config = {
                headers: { 'APIKey': 'REDACTED'}
            }
            this.$axios.post('REDACTED', this.userObject, config).then(response =>
            {
                if (response.data.includes("ERROR"))
                {
                    this.success = false
                    this.result = response.data
                }
                else
                {
                    this.success = true
                    this.result = ''
                    const auth = {
                        accessToken: response.data
                    }
                    this.$store.commit('setAuth', auth)
                    Cookie.set('auth', auth)

                    this.getAccountInfo()
                }
            }).catch(error =>{ console.log(error) })      
        },
        getAccountInfo: function() {
            const config = {
                headers: { 'APIKey': 'REDACTED', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  this.$store.state.auth.accessToken }
            }
            this.$axios.get('REDACTED', config).then(response =>
            {
                if (response != null && response.data != null)
                {
                    this.$store.commit('setFirst', response.data.First)
                    Cookie.set('first', response.data.First)

                    if (this.$store.state.fit)
                        this.$router.replace({ path: '/shop' })
                    else
                        this.$router.replace({ path: '/' })
                }
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
        }
```

POST canceled
only on iOS devices

Comment: It's unknown what performancehide and performanceshow are, only you can check where they are used and how they can affect it. Considering it appears in Mobile Safari, can you replicate the problem in OS X Safari?

Comment: Yes, this was replicated in OSX Safari.  The issue turned out to be with something in SSL on the IIS server.  There was an issue only impacting the SSL handshake on Safari / iOS.